# Django Inclusion Tag SyntaxError

Tags: python, django, templates, object, tags

Trying to follow the [Django Inclusion Tag documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) to create a custom template tag, but getting a template syntax error on line 6: `def types(Information)`.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('edit.html')
def types(Information)
    informations = Information.objects.all()
    return {'informations': informations}
```

The `templatetag.py` file is within the `/templatetags` directory.

The model for Information:

```
class Information(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    models = models.ManyToManyField('Model')
```

The template (edit.html):

```
{% load templatetag %}
<ul>
   {% for information in informations %}
      <li> {{ information }} </li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Am I misunderstanding how to create the inclusion tag and objects? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not surprisingly, you have a syntax error. Function definitions, like anything that starts a block in Python, need to have a colon at the end:

```
def types(information):
```

Also note that for some reason you've named your argument `Information`, which will hide the class Information - whatever object you pass as the actual parameter will be used as the base for the `objects.all()` query, which is unlikely to work.